# C# Export to CSV problems

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebresponse

I am using a method that accepts datatable and transform it into CSV. The problem is, (1) when I try to call this method, succeeding process/commands will never be executed. Also (2) list box contents from the calling form were cleared out after calling this method. Can anyone help me out on this? I have included the method below for reference.

```
public void DataTableToCSV(string fileName, DataTable dt)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.csv", fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(" ", "").Replace(":", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("/", "")));
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.csv";
    System.IO.StringWriter sWriter;
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    sWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
    string Str;
    for (int k = 0; k <= (dt.Columns.Count - 1); k++)
    {
        sWriter.Write(dt.Columns[k].ColumnName + ",");
    }

    sWriter.WriteLine(",");
    for (int i = 0; i <= (dt.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= (dt.Columns.Count - 1); j++)
        {
            Str = (dt.Rows[i][j].ToString().Replace(",", ""));
            if (Str == "&nbsp;")
                Str = "";

            Str = (Str + ",");
            sWriter.Write(Str);
        }
        sWriter.WriteLine();
    }
    sWriter.Close();
    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: How you call this method? use ajax call?

Comment: I supppose it is Asp.Net Webform?

Comment: [You may find this helpful!](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp)

Comment: Have you considered using http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Regarding (1) - `Response.End()` throws `ThreadAbortException` internally, which basically terminates the normal page life-cycle and 'jumps ahead' to the `EndRequest` event.  So anything immediately following a call to `DataTableToCSV()` will not be called.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Create a second page that returns the CSV. Put a Meta refresh tag in the head of your page which redirects to this page. Because the reponse is a file, you'll never actually be redirected, but the file save dialogue will appear.